# How to get selective logs from log4j.properties file

Tags: java

I have created a java project using Eclipse. In that project i used log4j.properties file. In the project in some cases i used the statements like

```
logger.debug("This is from debug");
logger.info("This is from Info");
```

My log file is

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
#log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
#log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

# Set the enterprise logger category to FATAL and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.enterprise=DEBUG, stdout

# Root logger option
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout
 log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
 log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x – %m%n
```

Now when i run the project i got all the log statements. for ex. I am using Quartz timer in my Project so when i run the program i got Quartz's default statements like

```
16   [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler  ? Quartz Scheduler v.2.1.4 created.
```

But i want only custom log statements, i.e.Statements written by me.
How to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only custom log statements, switch off rootLogger, and configure you custom logging, e.g.

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
log4j.logger.com.mycompany=DEBUG, CONSOLE
```

Comment: i have added above two lines in my log file.But now i did not get any single log statement on console.

Comment: log4j.logger.com.mycompany=DEBUG, CONSOLE means that Logger.getLogger("com.mycompany").debug("test"); will print on console. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement class level loggers as below

> log4j.logger.package.classes.classOne=INFO, LOGFILE

Make sure you remove other log4j keys (or comment it) so that only yours are logged

Comment: Don't know how that's configured with properties file but with xml-config you can also configure a logger "prachi" and in the code you would go like Logger prachLog = Logger.getLogger("prachi"); prachLog.info("Log prachi's stuff."); You can get that logger in several classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the logger for your package and class explicitly as following

```
log4j.logger.com.mycompany=INFO
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.MyClass=DEBUG
```