# Disable logging from log4j 2 library, how?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I'm using log4j 2 for logging and want to turn off the log messages from the library itself, e.g.:

```
2017-02-20 07:36:38,160 main DEBUG Took 0.001600 seconds to load 0 plugins from package org.apache.logging.log4j.test
```

I got the following in my `log4j2.XML` file but I still get `DEBUG` messages like the one above:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.logging" level="error" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
</Logger>
```

This question is not a duplicate of [Disabling Log4J Output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960)
because I don't want to turn off all output, only the output from the log4j 2 library itself. So I still want my code to generate log output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Log4J Output in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java)

Comment: @Leozeo no, it's not a duplicate, I edited the question to explain why.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891080/how-to-get-selective-logs-from-log4j-properties-file but its related to log4j not log4j 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can control the internal logging Log4j2 prints to the console with the `status` attribute at the top of the configuration file.

I would recommend that you switch off the verbose `debug`-level logging but keep the `warn` and `error` level logging so you get informed when something goes wrong.

To do this, change the beginning of the configuration file to this:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, reference link: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 3):

Set logging root level to `<Root level="off">`

Comment: This would turn off all logging, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you are migrating from log4j 1.x as I am trying to do.
I've correctly configured log4j2 but somehow there was still log4j as inherited dependency (and a inherited configuration) in my project.
The side effect of that is that both log4j are able to log, this is pretty annoying and pretty impossible to debug.